# system() yields inconsistent results

Tags: shell, date, awk

I am using awk to add a column to a CSV file. Each line of the file starts with a date & time.
I want the new column to be that time as a Unix epoch timestamp.

I'm feeding the first three fields to 'date' which does give me the timestamp, but there are some stray commas "," that I don't want. Below is a simplified version printing just that one timestamp column as output.  Input file:

```
08/17/2020 21:46:04 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3
08/17/2020 21:47:03 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3
08/17/2020 21:48:03 -700 , 1 , 2 
08/17/2020 21:49:04 -700 , 1 , 2
```

Here is my program:

```
cat input.csv | awk '{
       tmp=$(system("date +%s -d \""$1" "$2" "$3"\""));
       printf("%s", $tmp );
       }'
```

and here is the output. This is what I expect, except for the leading commas on lines 2 and 3.  I think the 'tmp' variable gets the result from 'date' including a trailing newline, but also sometimes with a comma after the newline.  It seems to depend on how many fields in the input file follow the first three, but I only reference the first three, as $1 $2 $3 so the rest of the input line plays no role (?)  Why do those comma show up in the output, and how could I remove them? Is there a better way to do this?

```
1597725964
,1597726023
,1597726083
1597726144
```

Comment: Your `tmp=$(system ...)` does not make sense. AFIK, you can't catch stdout from a command executed by `system` in awk. `system` itself would return the exit code of the command, but this would then be `tmp=system(....)`, without the `$`. Also, while `gawk` does support `system`, you did not give any information about the platform you are using, there is no guarantee that an `awk` really does have the `system` function available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Using shell

Try:

```
$ while read -r line; do date +%s -d "${line%%,*}"; done < input.csv
1597725964
1597726023
1597726083
1597726144
```

#### How it works

1. `while read -r line; do` starts a `while` loop and reads a line from stdin.
2. `"${line%%,*}"` strips the commas and everything after them from the line.
3. `date +%s -d "${line%%,*}"` prints the date as epoch.
4. `done` completes the `while` loop.
5. `<input.csv` provides the stdin to the loop.

## Variation

This prints the full line and adds the epoch as the final column:

```
$ while read line; do printf "%s, %s\n" "$line" $(date +%s -d "${line%%,*}"); done < input.csv
08/17/2020 21:46:04 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3, 1597725964
08/17/2020 21:47:03 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3, 1597726023
08/17/2020 21:48:03 -700 , 1 , 2, 1597726083
08/17/2020 21:49:04 -700 , 1 , 2, 1597726144
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply, concise and well explained! It does solve the simplified problem, but my ultimate goal is to generate on the output the entire input line plus a new column with the epoch. I know how to do that in awk which was why I went that way but maybe there's a simple modification of your proposal which does that also?

Comment: @JohnBeale I just added code to the answer which adds the epoch as a new column.

Comment: Thank you both. John1024  your "Variation" code does exactly what I wanted. I hope it may be useful to others, though maybe won't be found in a search, as my question title was based on my misunderstanding of how awk system() works.

Answer (score 6):

In `awk` you can use a coprocess with getline instead of system():

```
< input.csv awk -F' , ' '{
    "date +%s -d \047"$1"\047\n" | getline date
    print date
}'
1597725964
1597726023
1597726083
1597726144
```

With the help of [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462381/system-yields-inconsistent-results/63463371?noredirect=1#comment112223042_63463371) and [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462381/system-yields-inconsistent-results/63463371?noredirect=1#comment112222620_63463371) in comments, and `gawk`, we came up with a better solution, which writes into date's stdin, instead of passing the arguments via command line to it. That's better because interpolating variables into a command line always comes with the risk of shell command injection (via input.csv).

```
< input.csv gawk -F' , ' '{
    cmd = "date +%s -f-";
    print $1 |& cmd;
    close(cmd, "to");
    if ((cmd |& getline line) > 0)
        print line; close(cmd)
}'
1597725964
1597726023
1597726083
1597726144
```

Thanks to both!

Comment: @oguzismail: Did you mean to do this using the 2-way comm? `< file awk -F' , ' '{ cmd = "date +%s -f-"; print $1 |& cmd; close(cmd, "to"); if ((cmd |& getline line) > 0) print line; close(cmd) }'`?

Comment: @oguzismail I need to say my first test didn't work out, was hanging. Will check back later here. I  think it would be better to write to date's stdin, as you suggested, instead of interpolating the argument to the command line. The latter comes with the known risk of command injection.

Comment: @Inian will try that

Comment: @oguzismail: But I see the docs say, to alleviate, any buffering issues, its designed the write end must be closed before the coprocess can read. A bufferless read as you say, doesn't exist I think - unless you write it ;)

Comment: wow, it seems someone / something really removed my "Thank you both!!" comment :)

Answer (score 5):

The call to `system(...)` returns zero, thus `tmp` is assigned `$(0)`, i.e. the whole input line. Observe:

```
$ echo a b c d | awk '{ x = $(system("exit 3")); print x }'
c
```

You can't capture a shell command's output using the `system` function in awk; [hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463371/10248678) demonstrates how to do it correctly.

Then in the `printf(...)` call `$tmp` is expanded to `$8`, because the longest prefix in `$0` that constitutes a valid number is `08`; hence the commas in the output. Which can be proven like so:

```
$ echo foo bar | awk '{ x = "0002junk"; print $x }'
bar
```

Anyways, for achieving the task described in the question, you don't really need awk. A conjunction of `cut` and GNU `date` yields the desired output.

```
$ cut -d, -f1 input.csv | date -f- +%s
1597725964
1597726023
1597726083
1597726144
```

And using `paste`, you can append these timestamps to corresponding records if you don't mind missing spaces around commas.

```
$ cut -d, -f1 input.csv | date -f- +%s | paste -d, input.csv -
08/17/2020 21:46:04 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3,1597725964
08/17/2020 21:47:03 -700 , 1 , 2 , 3,1597726023
08/17/2020 21:48:03 -700 , 1 , 2,1597726083
08/17/2020 21:49:04 -700 , 1 , 2,1597726144
```

Comment: While it is clear to me that `system` returns 0 here, I don't understand why the `$(...)` used by the OP does not cause a syntax error.  What obscure awk feature is lurking here?

Comment: @Inian : Of course, the `$()` is nonsense, but for curiosity I tried it out, and at least it did not cause an error message, so it seems to do _something_. In any case, it does not seem to modify the value of `tmp`, which still is bound to the input line afterwards.

Comment: @user1934428 It is not a syntax error. In awk you can't use `$3+3` to get the sixth field, you need parantheses around the expression, like `$(3+3)`. In this case, `system` returns zero, and `tmp` is assigned `$(0)`, which is the same as `$0`.

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`. You could use `mktime` function of `awk` itself while using it you need not to use external commands `awk` itself could take care of it.

```
awk '
{
  split($2,array,":")
  print mktime(substr($0,7,4)" "substr($0,1,2)" "substr($0,4,2) OFS array[1] OFS array[2] OFS array[3])
}' Input_file
```

Comment: `mktime` is a GNU Awk extension.

Comment: I believe some versions of `mawk` also have `mktime`.